# Alternative for NewMailEx

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, vsto

Is there any other alternative for the event NewMailEx which fires inbox messages. The problem presently I am facing is that NewMailEx works only if the Internet is ON. It fires for incoming messages from the Exchange Server but not for cached messages in Exchange Server.

**"For users with an online Exchange Server account (non-Cached Exchange Mode), the event will fire only if Outlook is running. The event will not fire for the items that are received using an online Exchange Server account when Outlook is not running."**

What other alternative can I try to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anything related to Outlook automation, check [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), it's cheap, the license is not restrictive, and most of all it rocks.

RDOSession.OnNewMail() should help in your use case.

Comment: Can I use redemption with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for development and deployment

Comment: yes you can The development dll shows a splash screen on register. The paid version does not

Comment: can you help me get started to experiment with Redemption tutorials?